# How big in bytes is a DataRow

Tags: c#

I have a one-time process (hashing all our user passwords) written using datasets.  The performance needs improvement so we've profiled the application and found that increasing the 'batch size' of the update will improve performance.  I also know that if I load the entire data set into memory the application will start hitting swap and slow down.

The question is: how big is a System.Data.DataRow derived class?  I'd like to calculate a batch size which I know won't force the application into swap.

Comment: Not a real answer, but the question seems strange to me, because I don't see why you would ever have to keep a whole bunch of passwords in memory at once in order to hash them one at a time.  Is there some way you can do this without putting them all in a DataSet?

Comment: Basically this is a data migration issue.  We're moving users from a system where the passwords are clear text to one where they're hashed.  There was some discussion of using SqlBulkCopy to insert the records into the target table and creating a special data reader implementation which would hash the passwords on the fly and such.  It ended up being pretty complicated to implement.  Given that this is a one-time process it didnt seem worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're putting in the `DataRow`.  There's not an easy, framework-wide way of getting the size of managed objects, but if you know what is going in there you can do some relatively intelligent estimates based on the data sizes of the components themselves.

The overhead of the [`DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) class itself should be small comparatively - if you look at the properties, they're mostly dependent upon the `Item`s inside of it.

Again with no way to get the size of a managed object, you may be best off just doing some testing with known sizes and doing calculation tweaking based on that.  For something like this, you're not going to get an exact number anyway as you can't exactly control the .NET allocator/garbage-collector to within a byte or two - just calculate the theoretical exact amount and then scale it back by a little bit.

Comment: The components of the data row are:
One Guid (the id)
Three strings: one variable size, up to 100 characters (the old password), one 48 characters (the salt), one 128 characters (the hashed password)

Basically I'm looking for some guidance as to what the overhead on a data row will be